# React Native: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to start a React-Native project.

The only two commands in the terminal I have done are:

```
npx create-expo-app rate-repository-app --template expo-template-blank@sdk-46
```

and

```
npx expo install react-native-web@~0.18.7 react-dom@18.2.0 @expo/webpack-config@^0.17.0
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'mimeTypes'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
```

All I want to do is just start a project - I have done nothing apart from that.

How do you get around the error?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade webpack-dev-server to 3.10.1

```
npm i webpack-dev-server@3.10.1
```

Seems like React Native does not work with webpack-dev-server >4.0.0

Comment: Thank you. I ran `npm i --save-dev webpack-dev-server@3.11.0` to match the version in `@expo/webpack-config`.